# How to put multiple images control in array or list in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 60 images control of . I have two requirements:

1. put all images control in array
2. I have an roll no of 6 digits. and I want to match first digit to index of first 10 Images control, then 2nd digit to next 10 images and so on...
   following is my code:

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //for roll no
        int rollNo = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RollNo"]);
        var rollNoArray = rollNo.ToString().Select(t => 
           int.Parse(t.ToString())).ToArray();
        int index1=0;
            int index2=0, index3=0, index4 = 0
            ,index5 = 0, index6 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rollNoArray.Length; i++)
        {
            //Response.Write(rollNoArray[i]+"<br>");
            LBLRollNo.Text += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + 
            rollNoArray[i].ToString();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                index1 = rollNoArray[0];
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                index2 = rollNoArray[1];
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                index3 = rollNoArray[2];
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                index4 = rollNoArray[3];
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                index5 = rollNoArray[4];
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                index6 = rollNoArray[5];
            }
        }
        Response.Write(index1);

        //index
        matchBubbles(index1);
        }
     }
      public void matchBubbles(int index)
       {
        Image[] a =new Image[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a[0] = Image0;
            a[1] = Image1;
            a[2] = Image2;
            a[3] = Image3;
            a[4] = Image4;
            a[5] = Image5;
            a[6] = Image6;
            a[7] = Image7;
            a[8] = Image8;
            a[9] = Image9;

            if (index == a[i])
            {

            }
        }
}
```

I want to manipulate the psd file in a way that Whatever rollno is return from previous .aspx page an image(in my folder) should be inserted in the exact place against the index of the roll no means there is 10 boxes below for every digit and I want to insert the image there according to each digit of the roll no. Please help me!
Help me Please

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what your are looking for? Assume Roll No. is 123456, what is your expected result?

Comment: Hi Mike Actually I have 10 images at the bottom of every digit of my roll no.. I want to make that image visible whose index is equal to the value of the roll no.

Comment: Is 60 images in same array (index 0 to 59) or 6 arrays with 10 images each?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I want to manipulate the psd file in a way that Whatever rollno is return from previous .aspx page an image(in my folder) should be inserted in the exact place against the index of the roll no means there is 10 boxes below for every digit and I want to insert the image there according to each digit of the roll no. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case, you can do it simple way.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Check Roll No query string cannot be null
            if (Request["RollNo"] != null)
            {
                //Check Roll No cannot exeed 6 digits
                if (Request["RollNo"].Length <= 6)
                {
                    string RollNo = Request["RollNo"];

                    //Check Roll No. must be all digits
                    int iRollNo;
                    if (Int32.TryParse(RollNo, out iRollNo))
                    {
                        //Prefix with zero for RollNo less than 6 digits
                        if (RollNo.Length < 6)
                        {
                            RollNo = new String('0', 6 - RollNo.Length) + RollNo;
                        }

                        //Display 6 images
                        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Number/" + RollNo[0] + ".png";
                        Image2.ImageUrl = "~/Number/" + RollNo[1] + ".png";
                        Image3.ImageUrl = "~/Number/" + RollNo[2] + ".png";
                        Image4.ImageUrl = "~/Number/" + RollNo[3] + ".png";
                        Image5.ImageUrl = "~/Number/" + RollNo[4] + ".png";
                        Image6.ImageUrl = "~/Number/" + RollNo[5] + ".png";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Put 10 images in website]

Result

if RollNo. not all digits or more than 6 digits, not display
if RollNo. less than 6 digits, prefix with zero

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion that also comes with a lot of other tips:
Assuming you have a webforms project, enter this into your default.aspx file (not the default.aspx.cs) If you have all this happening in another file, well then you insert it all into that particular one:

```
<asp:Panel ID="HeaderPanel" runat="server">
        <h1>Enter image roll sequence here</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="RollNo" runat="server" Text="012345"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="send" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="LBLRollNo" runat="server" Text="Text coming in from QueryString will end up here after postback"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>      

    <asp:Panel ID="ImagePanel" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
```

Then you can paste this into your default.aspx.cs file (or whatever name you use instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This happens whenever there is a rollno variable coming in from the querystring
            if (Request.QueryString["RollNo"] != null)
            {
                string RollNo = Request.QueryString["RollNo"];                
                ShowImages(RollNo);
            }
        }

        // this happens when you enter the roll numbers in the text box and hit the send button
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RollNo.Text))
            {
                LBLRollNo.Text = " Selected roll numbers" + RollNo.Text;
                ShowImages(RollNo.Text);
            }
        }

        // Roll variable is the roll number. Imageno is the image number inside each Roll. And this information is stored in the image ID attribute.
        protected void ShowImages(string RollNumbers)
        {
            LBLRollNo.Text = " Selected roll numbers" + RollNumbers;
            var rollNoArray = RollNumbers.Select(t => int.Parse(t.ToString())).ToArray();

            foreach (int rollno in rollNoArray)
            {
                // add a HTML newline, just to make it more neat
                Literal templiteral = new Literal();
                templiteral.Text = "<br/>";
                ImagePanel.Controls.Add(templiteral);

                Label templabel = new Label();
                templabel.Text = "Images in roll number " + rollno.ToString();
                ImagePanel.Controls.Add(templabel);

                // Lay out the images belonging to this roll number (rollno)
                for (int Imageno = 0; Imageno <= 5; Imageno++)
                {
                    string identity = "ident|" + rollno.ToString() + "|" + Imageno.ToString() + "|"; // The IDs of each image on-screen will bear an ID like this: ident|0_0|
                    Image tempimage = new Image();
                    tempimage.ID = identity;
                    ImagePanel.Controls.Add(tempimage);
                }
            }
        }

        // This routine lays out all rolls and images in one go
        protected void LayOutImages()
        {
            for (int Roll = 0; Roll <= 10; Roll++)
            {
                Label templabel = new Label();
                templabel.Text = "Roll number " + Roll.ToString();
                ImagePanel.Controls.Add(templabel);

                for (int Imageno = 0; Imageno <= 5; Imageno++)
                {
                    string identity = "ident|" + Roll.ToString() + "|" + Imageno.ToString() + "|"; // The IDs of each image on-screen will bear an ID like this: ident|0_0|
                    Image tempimage = new Image();
                    tempimage.ID = identity;
                    ImagePanel.Controls.Add(tempimage);
                }
                Literal templiteral = new Literal();
                templiteral.Text = "<br/>";
                ImagePanel.Controls.Add(templiteral);
            }
        }
```

Run it and observe that you do not need an array of image controls. You can either enter a variable in the querystring, or you can set the roll numbers in the text box. By the way. When parsing a string array starting wqith 0 from the querystring, the leading zero will not be considered, but it is fixed in this one.

[image]

The idea is that each image has an identity telling you what roll number it belongs to and what image number the image has in any given roll

Hope this helps